# CSS Bootstrap Column goes outside row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="ticket_statistic_box">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-5 iconarea">
                <span class="   fa fa-briefcase ticket-icon"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="ticket_statistic_box_information">
                  <span>Total</span>
                  <span>0</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

I have set the background of `.iconarea` to white, which is the left part of the ticket statistic box in the row, and this results with that:

[image: img]

Look at the left one, and look at the right one, it should only fill over the background part of `.ticket_statistic_box`, but it goes outside?

```
.ticket_statistic_box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ticket_statistic_box span.ticket-icon {
  line-height: 110px;
}

.ticket_statistic_box_information span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.ticket_statistic_box_information span:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.ticket_statistic_box_information span:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #eda248;
}

.ticket-icon {
  color: #eda248;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 50pt;
}

.iconarea {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Have I done some nasty mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be one of this, since this might have a bigger height than its parent div.

```
.ticket_statistic_box span.ticket-icon {
  line-height: 110px;
}

.ticket-icon {
  font-size: 50pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.ticket-icon` has a large font size that makes it larger than the `.iconarea` box that it resides inside. It's forcing the box to be larger. So if you make the font smaller it should fix it. Or rather than the font-size, change the line height. Your line height is huge.

Comment: I tried the font size, it has no effect. But line height did make effect for the height part, not the width

Comment: I thought the height was the issue?

Comment: As you can see, the width is the issue

Comment: Look really under the box, u see the beginning of another box, u can see how the width difference starts

Comment: Ah, I see. What if you take the `display:block` off of the `ticket_statistic_box` and put the background on the columns instead of the `ticket_statistic_box`. The display block might be interfering with how the columns and rows are coming out.